# dealing with ajax response from php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the data from the array in foreach .
I am sending a ajax get request to php file and get response with json & array.
But when I try to print what inside the array its broke..

My JS code:

```
        var url = $("#url").val();
        var type = 'F';
        var data_url = url + "manage/sources/ajax/ajax.php?type=GetBarber&gender=" + type ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: data_url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
             // response returning - > {"status":"success","data":["name541","name214"]}
            var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);
             for (i=0; i < json_obj.data.length; i++)
                  {
                    var payment = json_obj.data[i];
                    console.log(payment); // Just for debugging
                  }


                }
                });
```

I am trying to print what inside the data (names..) 
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the dataType set to json therefore `response` is already parsed to an object. So do not call $.parseJSON

```
for (i=0; i < response.data.length; i++)
{
    var payment = response.data[i];
    console.log(payment); // Just for debugging
}
```